# How to get std::bind refer the explicit constructor defined in class while providing pointer to class member function as arguement?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I'm using std::bind in my code as shown below:

```
std::bind(&Filter::odometryCallback, filter, std::placeholders::_1, odomTopicName, poseCallbackData,
                   twistCallbackData);
```

The `Filter` class has explicit constructors defined and hence no default constructors are generated by the compiler  (for this class).

Now, the above line of code throws error with message "use of deleted function" and mentioning the copy constructor of `Filter` class.

My requirement:

How to get `&Filter::odometryCallback` to be considered/evaluated as pointer of explicitly constructed class instance member function ?

Any solutions and detailed explanation would be helpful.

**Edit: Example code**

I suppose, most of the code below doesn't make much sense to understand the context. But this is what I have right now.

```
OdomFunc setupOdometryCallback(std::string odomTopicName, EkfFilter& filter)
{
  using namespace RobotLocalization;
  std::vector<int> updateVec = filter.loadUpdateConfig(odomTopicName);
  std::vector<int> poseUpdateVec = updateVec;
  std::fill(poseUpdateVec.begin() + POSITION_V_OFFSET, poseUpdateVec.begin() + POSITION_V_OFFSET + TWIST_SIZE, 0);
  std::vector<int> twistUpdateVec = updateVec;
  std::fill(twistUpdateVec.begin() + POSITION_OFFSET, twistUpdateVec.begin() + POSITION_OFFSET + POSE_SIZE, 0);

  int poseUpdateSum = std::accumulate(poseUpdateVec.begin(), poseUpdateVec.end(), 0);
  int twistUpdateSum = std::accumulate(twistUpdateVec.begin(), twistUpdateVec.end(), 0);

  bool differential = false;
  bool relative = false;
  bool pose_use_child_frame = false;
  double poseMahalanobisThresh = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  double twistMahalanobisThresh = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  const CallbackData poseCallbackData(odomTopicName + "_pose", poseUpdateVec, poseUpdateSum, differential, relative,
                                      pose_use_child_frame, poseMahalanobisThresh);
  const CallbackData twistCallbackData(odomTopicName + "_twist", twistUpdateVec, twistUpdateSum, false, false, false,
                                       twistMahalanobisThresh);
  return std::bind(&EkfFilter::odometryCallback, filter, std::placeholders::_1, odomTopicName, poseCallbackData,
                   twistCallbackData);
}
```

**Edit 2: I forgot to paste these code below previously.**

The above Edit 1 & 2 code are in one `.cpp` file.

`setupOdometryCallback(parameters)` is a simple static function without any class.

```
using OdomFunc = std::function<void(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr&)>;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "ekf_node");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::NodeHandle nh_priv("~");

  std::string odomTopicName = "/husky_velocity_controller/odom";

  EkfFilter ekf(nh, nh_priv);
  ekf.initialize();

  auto odomF = setupOdometryCallback(odomTopicName, ekf);
}
```

Comment: Please form a proper [mre]. There is nothing in the shown code requiring a default construction of `Filter`.

Comment: I cannot add the code here because it's a very lengthy implementation.

However, I can paste the error.


`/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:128: error: use of deleted function `



`RobotLocalization::RosFilter<RobotLocalization::Ekf>::RosFilter(RobotLocalization::RosFilter<RobotLocalization::Ekf>&)’ `



This is because `&Filter::odometryCallback` tries to get function pointer from default constructed instance.


Note: `using Filter = RobotLocalization::RosEkf;`

`using RosFilter<Ekf> RosEkf;`

Comment: "_tries to get function pointer from default constructed instance_": There is no default constructed instance in anything you are showing and obtaining a function pointer doesn't require any instance at all.

Comment: Also the error message is complaining about a deleted copy constructor, not default constructor.

Comment: I know the error mentions copy constructor.


Explanation: When a class has no explicit constructors the compiler will implicitly generate the default constructor, default copy constructor, default copy assignment operator and finally default destructor. 


When a class explicit constructors defined, the above mentioned implicit constructors will not be generated.


In my problem, `Filter` Class has explicit constructors and the copy constructor is not defined in the class explicitly. So the compiler tries fallback for the default copy constructor.

Comment: "_When a class explicit constructors defined, the above mentioned implicit constructors will not be generated._" That is wrong. It applies only to the default constructor. "_So the compiler tries fallback for the default copy constructor._" It is called the _implicit_ copy constructor. None of this is enough to clearly explain what your problem is though. My best guess is that `filter` is of the problematic type, in which case you must make sure that `filter` is copy-constructible, because you are passing it as lvalue into `std::bind` which makes copies by copy/move from its arguments.

Comment: This is the relevant `class` [link](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/noetic-devel/include/robot_localization/ros_filter.h) and the `typedef` [link](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/noetic-devel/include/robot_localization/ros_filter_types.h).  What is the reason for the error ? (I have pasted the error in my first comment)

Comment: Please write up a complete [mre] and edit it into the question. If the example relies on a library, then tag the library as well.

Comment: I have added minimal reproducible example.

Comment: That's still not a [mre]. But if you want to have `std::bind` store a reference instead of a value to `filter`, then pass it `std::ref(filter)`, not `filter` directly. Or pass `&filter` if `odometryCallback` is a non-static member function. Or maybe better get rid of `std::bind` and use a lambda with reference-capture instead. If you don't simply want the closure to store a reference, but own the `filter` object instead, then take `filter` by rvalue reference and move it into the lambda/`std::bind`.

Comment: Few more lines of code added. Please refer these links clear understanding [link](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/noetic-devel/include/robot_localization/ekf.h), [link](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/noetic-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `std::bind` a reference parameter, you need to wrap it in `std::reference_wrapper`, as `bind` is an ordinary function, that does lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on it's arguments.

```
std::bind(&Filter::odometryCallback, std::ref(filter), std::placeholders::_1, odomTopicName, poseCallbackData, twistCallbackData);
```